# Facebook "Like" problem

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I create my first application and I'm testing like button, I use auto-generated code for button from facebook documentation. I click on button, everything seems to be ok, but next I want to retrieve "like data" from user, using https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes but my application is not there? I have done some tests using other applications, but everything was ok :-(

So, the question is, how i can retrieve this info?

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the user_likes extended permission from the user (when they authorize your application) to view their Likes. Further information can be found at:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

Comment: No, this is not the case, because i test app with my own account and i have access to like table, but among other previous likes there is no this from my application...

Comment: So just to confirm: have you requested the user_likes permission already? You can (for certain users/pages) retrieve *some* Like data, even when you haven't requested that permission, but it won't include all Like data unless you've requested user_likes.

Comment: I didn't have user_likes permissions, but I add this, remove application and use it again accepting new policies, but still same problem ;(

Comment: Can you copy and paste your auto-generated Like button code? It sounds like it's not liking your application correctly (or at least not the application you're expecting!)

Comment: <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
 <fb:like href="http://apps.facebook.com/kuba_test_dwa/" 
 layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="200" font="lucida grande">
 <meta property="og:tag name" content="tag value"/> 
 </fb:like>

Comment: I've tried similar code and my Like data shows up correctly. If you're still having problems, I would double check that you're checking for the correct "id" field. Just because you're Liking the apps.facebook.com/[your_app]/ URL, doesn't mean the ID of your application will appear in the Like data. It could be a new Facebook-assigned ID. Instead, I would check through all the "name" fields to see if there are any matches related to your application. Sorry I couldn't help further.